# Children's/young adult fantasy book about a boy who had an ability to tell what people were like by touching them

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, childrens-novel

I would like to find the title to a book I read a long long time ago about a boy who had an ability to tell what people were like by touching them. Instead of, say, feeling a human hand he would feel them as an animal that they were like; if they were devious, sneaky, etc., he might feel as if he had grabbed a snake or something.

Another element I seem to remember is a tower with a witch or something of the kind that was always weaving something, and he would somehow leave the tower (magically, teleport, etc.) to go to some other land for a quest or something.

I think there may have been a couple books about this same person. I would likely have read this in the late '80s or early to mid '90s, but I don't have any idea when it may have been written. Sorry this is so vague; the story has stuck with me all this time but not really in detail I guess.

Comment: If you find an answer that is correct, please mark it as such by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is [The Princess and Curdie](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/444380.The_Princess_and_Curdie) by George Macdonald. This is the second of two books; the first is called *The Princess and the Goblin*. They were written in 1872 and 1883, respectively. The "princess" (the young-old woman in the tower) grants Curdie the gift of judging a person's character by holding their hand. She demonstrates this to him by asking him to hold the hand of a creature in her care who was once human.

> 'Give Curdie a paw, Lina,' said the princess.
>
> The creature rose, and, lifting a long foreleg, held up a great
> doglike paw to Curdie. He took it gently. But what a shudder, as of
> terrified delight, ran through him, when, instead of the paw of a dog,
> such as it seemed to his eyes, he clasped in his great mining fist the
> soft, neat little hand of a child! He took it in both of his, and held
> it as if he could not let it go. The green eyes stared at him with
> their yellow light, and the mouth was turned up toward him with its
> constant half grin; but here was the child's hand! If he could but
> pull the child out of the beast! His eyes sought the princess. She was
> watching him with evident satisfaction.
>
> 'Ma'am, here is a child's hand!' said Curdie.
>
> 'Your gift does more for you than it promised. It is yet better to
> perceive a hidden good than a hidden evil.'

The princess does this because she wants to send Curdie to do something about a city with a corrupt leadership.

You can read [this book](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/709/pg709-images.html) at Project Gutenberg.

Comment: In *The Princess and the Goblin,* the titular princess is unambiguously Irene, who is a seven-year-old child.  However, in the sequel, both Irene and her immortal great-great-grandmother are referred to as princesses.